# Moveto not working while drawing path in svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, svg

I am creating an flag icon inside a svg and my code is

```
createSVG('path', {
            d:`M ${this.x},${this.y+this.height} ${this.x+6},${this.y+this.height} ${this.x+3},${this.y+this.height} ${this.x+3},${this.y} ${this.x+this.width-3},${this.y} ${this.x+this.width-3},${this.y+(this.height/2)} ${this.x+3},${this.y+(this.height/2)} M ${this.x+5} ${this.y+10} Z`,
            stroke: 'rgb(239, 86, 117)',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            fill: 'none',
            class: 'checkpoint',
            append_to: this.shape_group
        });
```

where this.x and this.y are coordinates
the createSVG function is defined as follows

```
function createSVG(tag, attrs) {
    const elem = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (let attr in attrs) {
        if (attr === 'append_to') {
            const parent = attrs.append_to;
            parent.appendChild(elem);
        } else if (attr === 'innerHTML') {
            elem.innerHTML = attrs.innerHTML;
        } else {
            elem.setAttribute(attr, attrs[attr]);
        }
    }
    return elem;
}
```

Above is the flag that I got
[image]

But Iam supposed to draw this
[image]

The thing is that Iam unable to move the start point to the center for the drawing the tick

```
d:`M ${this.x},${this.y+this.height} .......${this.y+(this.height/2)} Z M ${this.x+5} ${this.y+10} Z`,
```

I tried using **M** but its not working. Please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `The thing is that Iam unable to move the start point to the center for the drawing the tick` Where's the code to draw the tick?

Comment: the coordinates after the second M

Comment: I have a coordinate which is not showing up

Comment: **one coordinate**! What should show up, with only one endpoint?

Comment: Yes you are right, it worked when I added the second coordinate.
Thanks man..

Comment: With issues, always check your d-path in: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/